Application.MacroOptions ArgumentDescriptions not working in Excel (Office 365 version)
I can use the Application.MacroOptions method to define parameters for a User Defined Function, but the ArgumentDescriptions does not seem to work. Could anyone suggest what I may be doing wrong?
Here is my UDF:
Function sum_test(p1, p2)

    sum_test = p1 + p2

End Function

Here is the macro I use to register my function:
Sub Register_sum_test()
Dim sum_test_Args() As String
Dim sum_test_Desc As String
Dim test

    sum_test_Desc = "adds two numbers"
    
    ReDim sum_test_Args(1 To 2)
    sum_test_Args(1) = "first number"
    sum_test_Args(2) = "second number"
    
    Application.MacroOptions Macro:="Personal.xlsb!sum_test", Description:=sum_test_Desc
    Application.MacroOptions Macro:="Personal.xlsb!sum_test", ArgumentDescriptions:=sum_test_Args
    
End Sub

After running the macro, I can see the "Description" parameter has been applied within excel. However the "ArgumentDescriptions" do not appear:
Snip of Function Wizard

It works on my end. I used Book1 (new workbook) instead of Personal.xlsb. When I create a function in Personal.xlsb, it doesn't show in the list of functions so I wonder what is the purpose of keeping a function there and if your idea is even a possibility. I keep my UDFs in an add-in and they are always available (if the add-in is open) in any workbook. Maybe that's the way for you to go.

Hi @VBasic2008. Thanks very much! I tested using a new workbook and you are right: the UDF parameter descriptions then work. Strange. Incidentally, the UDFs and macros that I define in Personal.xlsb are always available to any workbook. Not sure why that would not work for you. However, as you suggest, using an add-in may be the way to go to get my desired parameter descriptions working!

When I copy your function to my PERSONAL.xlsb and start typing in a cell of another worksheet =sum_ after the underscore, the Intellisense (list of functions) disappears. When I finish with =sum_test(1,2) I get the #NAME? error confirming once more that there is no sum_test. Could you try and confirm that this doesn't happen on your end? All subs are of course available in the macro-dialog.

@VBasic2008, the function only appears in the "Insert Function" box when you click the "fx" command next to the data entry bar. It appears under "User Defined" . The formula becomes =PERSONAL.XLSB!sum_test(1,2)

It should be:
ReDim sum_test_Args(0 To 1)
sum_test_Args(0) = "first number"
sum_test_Args(1) = "second number"

